# How to ocr the combination of the number and the letter?

Tags: ocr

I know the command `tesseract image.tif outputbase nobatch digits` to recognize the number and `tesseract image.tif outputbase` to get the letter result. But if I get a image with the combination of the **letter and number** how to recognize it ?